# How to get photos back which weren't saved to my iCloud account?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I had to repair my phone and forgot to save all of my photos to my iCloud account. Is there any way I can get them back?

Comment: Never connected to a computer and synched with iPhoto (or some folder on Windows)? Never used Dropbox sync or another cloud solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the phone was erased as part of the repair, no, there is no way to get them back.